# Initialization error between classes

Tags: java, class, variables, object

When ever I put Checking and Saving objects and try to call them in another class, it does not actually work, and it gives me a syntax error. I have pasted my java code below. For whatever reason, it has trouble with the Account. Is there anything that I should change so as to avoid having these errors?

The errors given are:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    SavingsAccount cannot be resolved to a type
    SavingsAccount cannot be resolved to a type
    Customer cannot be resolved to a type
    bank cannot be resolved
    accountentered cannot be resolved to a variable
    accountentered cannot be resolved to a variable
    transAccount cannot be resolved to a variable
    transAccount cannot be resolved to a variable
    SavingsAccount cannot be resolved to a type
    SavingsAccount cannot be resolved to a type
    Customer cannot be resolved to a type
    Customer cannot be resolved to a type
    Duplicate local variable amount
    CreditAccount cannot be resolved to a type
    CreditAccount cannot be resolved to a type
    Duplicate local variable firstName
    Duplicate local variable lastName
    Duplicate local variable pnumber
    Customer cannot be resolved to a type
    Duplicate local variable newCustomer
    Customer cannot be resolved to a type

```
at ProjectBank.main(ProjectBank.java:25)

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerDemo
{

    class Customer
    {
        //two objects/ saving and checking
        Account Saving = new Account();
        Account Checking = new Account();
        public Customer(InputStream in)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        boolean deposit(double amount, String acc)
        {
            double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
            boolean retVal = false;
            switch (acc)
            {
            case "Checking":
                if(amount >=0)
                {
                    currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
                    retVal = true;
                }
                break;
            case "Saving":
                if(amount >=0)
                {
                    currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.deposit(amount);
                    retVal = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        boolean withdraw(double amount, String acc)
        {
            double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
            boolean retVal = false;
            switch (acc)
            {
            case "Checking":
                if(amount >=0)
                {
                    currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
                    retVal = true;
                }
                break;
            case "Saving":
                if(amount >=0)
                {
                    currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.withdraw(amount);
                    retVal = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        boolean transfer(double amount, String acc)
        {
            double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
            boolean retVal = false;

            switch (acc)
            {
            case "Checking":
                if(amount >=0)
                {
                    currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
                    currentBalanceSaving = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
                    retVal = true;
                }
                break;
            case "Saving":
                if(amount >=0)
                {
                    currentBalanceSaving = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
                    currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
                    retVal = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
    void printBalance()
    {
    }
}
class Account
{
    double balance;
    //the constructor tells the customer that there are zero dollars in the account.
    Account()
    {
        balance = 0;
    }
    //deposit money
    double deposit( double depAmount )
    {
        balance= balance + depAmount;//balance+ = depAmount
        return balance;
    }
    double withdraw( double withAmount )
    {
        balance= balance - withAmount;//balance- = withAmount
        return balance;
    }
    double transferToSaving(double transAmount)
    {
        Checking.balance = balance - transAmount;
        Saving.balance = balance + transAmount;
    }

    double transferToChecking(double transAmount)
    {
        Checking.balance = balance - transAmount;
        Saving.balance = balance + transAmount;
    }
    double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
}

class run
{
    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Customer customer = new Customer(System.in);
        int accountChoice; // show which account needs to be chosen.
        String cusSel; //for customer selection.
        double money;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("main menu to be selected: " );
            System.out.println("1.deposit " );
            System.out.println("2.withdraw " );
            System.out.println("3.transfer " );
            System.out.println("4.print balance " );
            System.out.println("q.quit " );
            cusSel=in.next();
            switch(cusSel.charAt(0))
            {
            case '1':
                System.out.println("please select account: " );
                System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                System.out.println("2. Saving " );
                accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                {
                    System.out.println("please imput the deposit amount: " );
                    money=in.nextDouble();
                    if(accountChoice==1)
                    {
                        customer.deposit(money, "Checking");
                    }
                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                    {
                        customer.deposit(money, "Saving");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case '2':

                System.out.println("Please select account: " );
                System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                System.out.println("2. Saving " );

                accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                {
                    System.out.println("please input the withdraw amount: " );

                    money=in.nextDouble();


                    if(accountChoice==1)
                    {
                        customer.withdraw(money, "Checking");
                    }
                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                    {
                        customer.withdraw(money, "Saving");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case '3':

                System.out.println("please select an account to transfer from: " );
                System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                System.out.println("2. Saving " );

                accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                {
                    System.out.println("please input the withdraw amount: " );

                    money=in.nextDouble();

                    if(accountChoice==1)
                    {
                        customer.transfer(money, "saving");
                    }
                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                    {
                        customer.transfer(money, "checking");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case '4':
                customer.printBalance();
                break;
            case 'q':
                System.out.println("transaction complete, please have a nice day");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid choice.");

            }

        } while (cusSel.charAt(0)!= 'q' && cusSel.charAt(0)!= 'Q');

    }
    private void getAccountChoice(int accountChoice) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: What error does it give? Also, don't use capital initial letters for member variables. Also, can you fix your indentation so it's easier to read for the people you are asking for help?

Comment: I edited the indentation to match Eclipse's standard. The errors are on the Account class on the transferToSaving and the transferToChecking methods. There is also an error on the main method on this line, saying that Customer cannot be resolved to a variable.    Customer customer = new Customer(System.in);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because you declare objects in customer class and you try to access them from account as local variables.

The reason you got to this error is your class structure. A class should only have methods and fields that are DIRECTLY relevant to a single instance of your class. For instance in your case Account class has "balance" which is 100% correct and then it has methods like "transferToSavings()" (that don't even use that variable) that are relevant to CONNECTION (which in this case is the customer, or normally a transaction) between Checking account and Savings account rather than to account itself.

The basic structure of a transfer should be like this:

```
Customer{
   Account Saving = new Account();
   Account Checking = new Account();

   //you have something similar with input control
   void tranferFunds(Account from, Account to, double amount){

      from.Withdraw(amount);
      to.Deposit(amount);
   }

}

class Account
{
    double balance;
    Account()
    {
        balance = 0;
    }
    void deposit( double amount)
    {
        balance+=  amount;
    }
    void withdraw( double amount)
    {
        balance-=  amount;
    }
    double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I noticed you already have a transfer() method in Customer, which should work fine, so you don't have to alter your customer class.

**Edit2:** It cannot resolve Customer because Your customer class is within CustomerDemo Class. You can remove CustomerDemo class alltogether (with accompanying brackets)

**Edit3:** Here's your code debugged and without the account.transferTo/from methods. I was using an online compiler so I coudn't test the input, but there are no more syntax errors:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class run
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Customer customer = new Customer(System.in);
        int accountChoice; // show which account needs to be chosen.
        String cusSel; //for customer selection.
        double money;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("main menu to be selected: " );
            System.out.println("1.deposit " );
            System.out.println("2.withdraw " );
            System.out.println("3.transfer " );
            System.out.println("4.print balance " );
            System.out.println("q.quit " );
            cusSel=in.next();
            switch(cusSel.charAt(0))
            {
            case '1':
                System.out.println("please select account: " );
                System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                System.out.println("2. Saving " );
                accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                {
                    System.out.println("please imput the deposit amount: " );
                    money=in.nextDouble();
                    if(accountChoice==1)
                    {
                        customer.deposit(money, "Checking");
                    }
                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                    {
                        customer.deposit(money, "Saving");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case '2':

                System.out.println("Please select account: " );
                System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                System.out.println("2. Saving " );

                accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                {
                    System.out.println("please input the withdraw amount: " );

                    money=in.nextDouble();


                    if(accountChoice==1)
                    {
                        customer.withdraw(money, "Checking");
                    }
                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                    {
                        customer.withdraw(money, "Saving");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case '3':

                System.out.println("please select an account to transfer from: " );
                System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                System.out.println("2. Saving " );

                accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                {
                    System.out.println("please input the withdraw amount: " );

                    money=in.nextDouble();

                    if(accountChoice==1)
                    {
                        customer.transfer(money, "saving");
                    }
                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                    {
                        customer.transfer(money, "checking");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case '4':
                customer.printBalance();
                break;
            case 'q':
                System.out.println("transaction complete, please have a nice day");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid choice.");

            }

        } while (cusSel.charAt(0)!= 'q' && cusSel.charAt(0)!= 'Q');

    }
    private void getAccountChoice(int accountChoice) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}

class Customer
{
    //two objects/ saving and checking
    Account Saving = new Account();
    Account Checking = new Account();
    public Customer(InputStream in)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    boolean deposit(double amount, String acc)
    {
        double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
        boolean retVal = false;
        switch (acc)
        {
        case "Checking":
            if(amount >=0)
            {
                currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
                retVal = true;
            }
            break;
        case "Saving":
            if(amount >=0)
            {
                currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.deposit(amount);
                retVal = true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    boolean withdraw(double amount, String acc)
    {
        double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
        boolean retVal = false;
        switch (acc)
        {
        case "Checking":
            if(amount >=0)
            {
                currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
                retVal = true;
            }
            break;
        case "Saving":
            if(amount >=0)
            {
                currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.withdraw(amount);
                retVal = true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    boolean transfer(double amount, String acc)
    {
        double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
        boolean retVal = false;

    switch (acc)
    {
    case "Checking":
        if(amount >=0)
        {
            currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
            currentBalanceSaving = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
            retVal = true;
        }
        break;
    case "Saving":
        if(amount >=0)
        {
            currentBalanceSaving = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
            currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
            retVal = true;
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
    }
    return retVal;
    }
    void printBalance()
    {
    }
    }


class Account
{
    double balance;
    //the constructor tells the customer that there are zero dollars in the account.
    Account()
    {
        balance = 0;
    }
    //deposit money
    double deposit( double depAmount )
    {
        balance= balance + depAmount;//balance+ = depAmount
        return balance;
    }
    double withdraw( double withAmount )
    {
        balance= balance - withAmount;//balance- = withAmount
        return balance;
    }

    double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
}
```